# Why es cluster stop to work until i delete the old index?

Tags: elasticsearch

In [es document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_coping_with_failure.html),it introduce that,`If we restart Node 1,If Node 1 still has copies of the old shards, it will try to reuse them, copying over from the primary shard only the files that have changed in the meantime`.

So I did an experiment.

Here are 5 nodes in my cluster,Primary shards `1` is saved in node `1`,and replica shards `1` is saved in node `2`.When i restart node `1` and node `2`,Primary shards `1`'s state become `UNASSIGNED`,and replica shards `1`'s state become `UNASSIGNED` too,the health of the cluster become `red`,and the health never become `green`.And the cluster stop to work until i delete the old index.

Here is part of the master log.

```
[ERROR][marvel.agent             ] [es10] background thread had an uncaught exception
ElasticsearchException[failed to flush exporter bulks]
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk.close(ExportBulk.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.run(AgentService.java:201)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: ElasticsearchException[failed to flush [default_local] exporter bulk]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failure in bulk execution, only the first 100 failures are printed:
[8]: index [.marvel-es-data], type [cluster_info], id [nm4dj3ucSRGsdautV_GDDw], message [UnavailableShardsException[[.marvel-es-data][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [shard bulk {[.marvel-es-data][1]}]]]];
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:106)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: ElasticsearchException[failure in bulk execution, only the first 100 failures are printed:
[8]: index [.marvel-es-data], type [cluster_info], id [nm4dj3ucSRGsdautV_GDDw], message [UnavailableShardsException[[.marvel-es-data][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [shard bulk {[.marvel-es-data][1]}]]]]
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.local.LocalBulk.flush(LocalBulk.java:114)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:101)
        ... 3 more
[2016-02-19 12:53:18,769][ERROR][marvel.agent             ] [es10] background thread had an uncaught exception
ElasticsearchException[failed to flush exporter bulks]
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk.close(ExportBulk.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.AgentService$ExportingWorker.run(AgentService.java:201)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: ElasticsearchException[failed to flush [default_local] exporter bulk]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failure in bulk execution, only the first 100 failures are printed:
[8]: index [.marvel-es-data], type [cluster_info], id [nm4dj3ucSRGsdautV_GDDw], message [UnavailableShardsException[[.marvel-es-data][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [shard bulk {[.marvel-es-data][1]}]]]];
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:106)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: ElasticsearchException[failure in bulk execution, only the first 100 failures are printed:
[8]: index [.marvel-es-data], type [cluster_info], id [nm4dj3ucSRGsdautV_GDDw], message [UnavailableShardsException[[.marvel-es-data][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [shard bulk {[.marvel-es-data][1]}]]]]
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.local.LocalBulk.flush(LocalBulk.java:114)
        at org.elasticsearch.marvel.agent.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.flush(ExportBulk.java:101)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: What do the master node logs show?

Comment: did it form the cluster successfully ?

Comment: @AndreiStefan,i added the master log just now.

Comment: @PandiyanCool,yes it formed the cluster successfully.

Comment: You probably started some wrong node, or you changed cluster name, cluster location, port number etc, that the data the node initially had cannot be found anymore. Not only you own index shards are missing but I see Marvel index shard is missing as well.

Comment: @AndreiStefan,When the health status is red,the cluster unable to index  any documents?

Comment: When it's `red` you cannot index documents in the `red` indices. The other indices can be indexed into. To see the status of each index, you can run `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices"`